# How to pass multiple arguments to Static Void Main in C#

Tags: c#, console-application, program-entry-point

I am trying to pass two arguments like :

```
static void Main(string[] args,string NewReportID)
```

But I am getting error stating "Main has the wrong signature to be entry point". Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you call your exe via `MyProgram.exe parameter1 parameter2` then in `args[0]` you will have `parameter1` and in `args[1]` you will have `parameter2`

Comment: FYI [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/) makes the mapping/parsing a lot easier once you pass in through `args`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Main has the wrong signature to be entry point"` means that `Main` need only one params

Move your `NewReportID` in `args`